# What is the meaning for the term kissing cousins?

Tags: meaning

Example: A nil-nil soccer game being like kissing cousins

Comment: Related: [Definition of “kissing cousins”— Are the dictionaries wrong/incomplete?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206118)

Comment: The answers to that question are inaccurate.

Answer (score -2):

A relative known well enough to be given a kiss in greeting.
I think

Comment: Expert partial answers are welcome, but notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers.

If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, a better way is to request clarification in a comment on the question.

A better place for debate or free-wheeling discussion is our [chat] (or, when one exists, the chatroom attached to the post itself).